# PHP search SQL data base

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, search

I have a MySQL database on my domain, than I made a table called AccountInformation. In that table are things like `AccountID`, `AccountName`, `FirstName`, `SecondName` etc.

I made a PHP program which connects to that database and is able to fetch all rows and display them, but thats not what I want it to do. I want to fetch information from a certain row depending on its ID.

Pseudo-Example :

```
 $UserName String

   $SearchID = 1

   $UserName = fetchrow where 'AccountID' = $SearchID and get 'AccountName' of that row
```

So that I now have the `UserName` of the account with the `ID 1` in `$UserName`.

Comment: So, you mean this?... `SELECT AccountName FROM AccountInformation WHERE AccountID = ?`  Then just bind the value to the parameter.

Comment: Something like `"SELECT AccountName FROM MyTable WHERE AccountID = {$SearchID};"`

Comment: These answers look all nice and right, and are similayr to the ones i found in the indernets. But if I know echo the result it just gives my empty although all enformation is put in right.

Comment: @HuRiXD Please post the actual code you're using to get the data from the database, not only an example of what you're trying to do. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this should be what you're looking for...

```
/* put the value of $number to the id number you want to get other info from*/
$number = "1";
$sql = mysql_query("select * from `AccountInformation` where `id`='$number';");

$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

echo $result["AccountName"];
```